# How to decompress .7z file in android

Tags: android, compression, shared-libraries, android-native-library

I want to uncompress .7z file which is getting from the server. 
for that, I was added sevenzipjbinding.jar library and its shared library sevenzipjbinding-AllLinux.jar into project libs directory 
but i am getting an error **"The library 'sevenzipjbinding-AllLinux.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device**" in console at time of run an application.

and I try to use `system.loadLibrary(sevenzipjbinding-AllLinux.jar);` in activity but again its giving same error.

Please, Tell me how to implement it. how to uncompress tar.7z

Comment: Search gave these results: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+7zip

Comment: @Rajesh Of which most aren't relevant and the ones that are aren't useful. (They point towards the native SDK, not a functioning Java one.)